# Accessing SQL Server 2012 from Windows XP

Tags: sql-server, windows-xp, sql-server-2012, compatibility

Is there a compatibility problem that would prevent a program running under Windows XP from accessing a SQL Server 2012 Standard instance running on a Windows 2008 server on the same domain?

This might be a stupid question; I know that it is not possible to *install* SQL Server 2012 on XP, but I cannot think of a reason why it would not allow access by a program.

So this is merely a stab in the dark. For the moment I only wish to know whether there are any problems *in principle*; if there are none I will try to come up with a minimal error case for my particular setup and ask a separate question.

Comment: Have you tried installed this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321.aspx

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065  Please report back, I don't know if the 2012 will install on XP, I'm just making a suggestion.

Comment: thanks, i will try; but I think the requirements for that exclude XP as well

Comment: If that doesn't install, then I think 2012 has left XP in the dust.......my guess anyways.

Comment: I can confirm that the sql server native client for 2012 will refuse to install on XP. But on the other hand, I do not think the native client had to be installed on any of the windows 7 PCs for them to be able to connect, I will have to investigate this further.

Comment: That is interesting.  Of course Windows 7 would have some kind of sql client pre-installed.  So I think you might try ... finding the Client-Package (2008?  2005?) that will actually install on XP, and see if that will allow you to talk to Sql Server 2012.  I don't know of all the backwards compatibility rules.

Comment: The test machines do have sql server 2008 express installed for testing purposes, and can also connect to other sql 2008 server instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just confirmed that an application written in VB6 using ADO with the "Microsoft OLEDB provider for SQL Server" can connect to a SQL Server 2012 database.  The connection string looks like this:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;
Password=PasswordHere;
Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=SomeUserName;
Initial Catalog=SomeDatabase;
Data Source=SQL2012Instance
```

The operating system is Microsoft Windows XP Service Pack 3.

The operating system hosting the SQL database is Win-7.

The database engine is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (x64)